# Делегаты C#. Invoke

Tags: c#, делегаты

В качестве примера возьмем следующий код и опустим все подробности.

```
private void Example(Func<bool> exampleFunction)
{
    bool result = exampleFunction();    // 1
    result = exampleFunction.Invoke();  // 2
}
```

В чем различие между первым и вторым вызовом функции? Опишите ситуации в которых важно применять либо первый, либо второй вызов делегата.

На  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) указано:

> Вызывает метод или конструктор, представленный текущим экземпляром,
>   используя указанные параметры.

Comment: _На msdn указано:_ добавь ссылку где это указано

Comment: @Grundy, добавил

Comment: Это не та ссылка. Там функция из reflection, а в коде нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На самом деле ваш объект `exampleFunction` имеет тип `Func<bool>`, его базовый тип `MulticastDelegate`, а у этого типа базовый тип `Delegate` (http://ideone.com/I99DiH).

Для потомков типа `Delegate` CLR предоставляет метод `Invoke` с сигнатурой, соответствующей объявлённой сигнатуре делегата. [Из MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The common language runtime provides an `Invoke` method for each delegate type, with the same signature as the delegate. You do not have to call this method explicitly from C#, Visual Basic, or Visual C++, because the compilers call it automatically. The `Invoke` method is useful in [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx) when you want to find the signature of the delegate type.

Это значит, что разницы нет, и обычно проще использовать просто вызов со скобками.

---

Несколько отдельных случаев, при которых `Invoke` имеет смысл использовать:

- Рефлексия. Имея объект делегатного типа, можно произвести вызов его через `Invoke`.
- Новый оператор `?.`: вместо

  ```
  if (exampleFunction != null)
      exampleFunction();
  ```

  можно написать более изящное

  ```
  exampleFunction?.Invoke();
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё метод Invoke позволяет преодолеть основной недостаток делегатов - несовместимость делегатов разных типов, но одной сигнатуры, по присваиванию.

```
EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> handler1 = new EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>(SomeHandler); 
Action<object, CancelEventArgs> handler2 = handler1; // Так нельзя!
handler2 = new Action<object, CancelEventArgs>(handler1.Invoke); // А так можно.
```