# Разница между Invoke и обычным вызовом делегата через ()

Tags: c#, делегаты

В чём разница между `Invoke` и обычным вызовом делегата через `()` в C#?

Comment: Думаю стоит перевести вопрос на русский...

Comment: Ни в чем. Вызов со скобками -- синтаксичеcкий сахар для Invoke.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Делегаты C#. Invoke](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610975/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-c-invoke)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для делегатов разницы между вызовом через `d.Invoke(список аргументов)` и `d(список аргументов)` нет.

При этом генерируется одинаковый IL-код: вызов через скобки транслируется в `Invoke`. ([Проверка](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgqSA2IgZiICYCBhKgbyoN6OPolWEAgF4CAOwCuGDBUp9+gpjgAsBACoALBAHspAcy0AFCAjgSYWuFBsAKAJRiAfAQiP5iuoyLrtewy0ASQkAN10AazhHFzcAOhDwqI8qAF8gA=).)

Интересное синтаксическое отличие состоит в том, что проверка на `null` с `Invoke`-синтаксисом проще: `d?.Invoke(список аргументов)`.

Документация: [Common Patterns for Delegates / Handling Null Delegates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/delegates-patterns#handling-null-delegates).

Также для вызова через рефлексию вам понадобится использовать `Invoke`, т. к. скобки на уровне рефлексии никак не представлены.